# Getting full contents of a Datagrid using UIAutomation

Tags: c#, .net, ui-automation

I have need to retrieve all of the items in a Datagrid from an external application using UIAutomation. Currently, I can only retrieve (and view in UISpy) the visible items. Is there a way to cache all of the items in the Datagrid and then pull them? Here's the code:

```
static public ObservableCollection<Login> GetLogins()
    {

        ObservableCollection<Login> returnLogins = new ObservableCollection<Login>();

        var id = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("<Name here>")[0].Id;
        var desktop = AutomationElement.RootElement;

        var bw = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, id));

        var datagrid = bw.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "lv"));

        var loginLines = datagrid.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.DataItem));

        foreach (AutomationElement loginLine in loginLines)
        {
            var loginInstance = new Login { IP = new IP() };

            var loginLinesDetails = loginLine.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Custom));

            for (var i = 0; i < loginLinesDetails.Count; i++)
            {
                var cacheRequest = new CacheRequest 
                { 
                    AutomationElementMode = AutomationElementMode.None,
                    TreeFilter = Automation.RawViewCondition
                };

                cacheRequest.Add(AutomationElement.NameProperty);
                cacheRequest.Add(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty);

                cacheRequest.Push();

                var targetText = loginLinesDetails[i].FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "TextBlock"));

                cacheRequest.Pop();

                var myString = targetText.Cached.Name;

                #region Determine data and write to return object
                //Removed private information
                #endregion
                }

            }

            returnLogins.Add(loginInstance);
        }

        return returnLogins;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only retrieve the visible cells because you have table virtualization on.

Try disabling the virtualization (not always possible in all application but perhaps you want to move it into configuration and change it before testing)

Comment: I feared as much, I don't have access to adjust the other application. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am 99% sure that this is not possible.  UI Automation doesn't know about the data structures which are represented by the currently visible portion of a grid.  It only sees what is visible.  I think that you will have to page through the grid to get all the data (that is what I do).