# UI Automation not working for DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, microsoft-ui-automation

After trying out several solutions, I am in desperate need for help.

I tried several approaches, before finally copying and still being stuck with the solution from [Getting full contents of a Datagrid using UIAutomation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129592/getting-full-contents-of-a-datagrid-using-uiautomation).

Let's talk code, please consider the comments:

```
// Get Process ID for desired window handle
uint processID = 0;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out processID);

var desktop = AutomationElement.RootElement;

// Find AutomationElement for the App's window
var bw = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, (int)processID));

// Find the DataGridView in question
var datagrid = bw.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "dgvControlProperties"));

// Find all rows from the DataGridView
var loginLines = datagrid.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.DataItem));

// Badumm Tzzz: loginLines has 0 items, foreach is therefore not executed once 

foreach (AutomationElement loginLine in loginLines)
{
    var loginLinesDetails = loginLine.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Custom));

    for (var i = 0; i < loginLinesDetails.Count; i++)
    {
        var cacheRequest = new CacheRequest 
        { 
            AutomationElementMode = AutomationElementMode.None,
            TreeFilter = Automation.RawViewCondition
        };

        cacheRequest.Add(AutomationElement.NameProperty);
        cacheRequest.Add(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty);

        cacheRequest.Push();

        var targetText = loginLinesDetails[i].FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "TextBlock"));

        cacheRequest.Pop();

        var myString = targetText.Cached.Name;
    }

}
```

I can neither fetch a `GridPattern`, nor a `TablePattern` instance from `datagrid`, both results in an exception:

```
GridPattern gridPattern = null;

try
{
    gridPattern = datagrid.GetCurrentPattern(GridPattern.Pattern) as GridPattern;
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    // It fails!
}

TablePattern tablePattern = null;

try
{
    tablePattern = datagrid.GetCurrentPattern(TablePattern.Pattern) as TablePattern;
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    // It fails!
}
```

The rows were added to the `DataGridView` beforehand, like this:

```
dgvControlProperties.Rows.Add(new object[] { false, "Some Text", "Some other text" });
```

I am compiling to .Net Framework 4.5. Tried both regular user rights and elevated admin rights for the UI Automation client, both yielded the same results described here.

Why does the `DataGridView` return 0 rows?

Why can't I get one of the patterns?

Kudos for helping me out!

---

## Update:

James help didn't to the trick for me. The following code tough returns all rows (including the headers):

```
var rows = dataGrid.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, PropertyCondition.TrueCondition);
```

Header cells can then be identified by their `ControlType` of `ControlType.Header`.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The object loginLines contains 0 items, though there are items within the DataGridView which where added with the aforementioned dgv.Rows.Add(...) method call.

Comment: So there is no exception here really, my program simply does not fetch the rows for no obvious reason (to me).

Comment: In your Catch blocks you wrote: "It fails." `tablePattern = datagrid.GetCurrentPattern(TablePattern.Pattern) as TablePattern;` is not throwing any errors?

Comment: Could you show the data-binding code in the context of its method and the form event handler methods?

Comment: This line fails: `var loginLines = datagrid.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.DataItem));`, because all children of the DGV are of ControlType.Header or simply ControlType.Custom.

Comment: Can this be a localization issue? I am using a german Win7.

Answer (score 4):

The code that you are copying is flawed. I just tested this scenario with an adaptation of [this sample program](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33049/WPF-UI-Automation) factoring in your code above, and it works.

The key difference is that the code above is using `TreeScope.Children` to grab the datagrid element. This option only grabs immediate children of the parent, so if your datagrid is nested it's not going to work. Change it to use `TreeScope.Descendants`, and it should work as expected.

```
var datagrid = bw.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "dgvControlProperties"));
```

[Here is a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.treescope.aspx) to how the various Treescope options behave. Also, I don't know how your binding the rows to the grid, but I did it like this in my test scenario and it worked flawlessly.

Hopefully this helps.

```
public class DataObject
{
    public string FieldA { get; set; }
    public string FieldB { get; set; }
    public string FieldC { get; set; }
}

List<DataObject> items = new List<DataObject>();
items.Add(new DataObject() {FieldA="foobar",FieldB="foobar",FieldC="foobar"});
items.Add(new DataObject() { FieldA = "foobar", FieldB = "foobar", FieldC = "foobar" });
items.Add(new DataObject() { FieldA = "foobar", FieldB = "foobar", FieldC = "foobar" });

dg.ItemsSource = items;
```

Comment: In this constructed case, the DataGridView was a direct child of the Form, thanks for the link anyway!

Comment: Switching between adding the Rows directly to the DGV and your code does not change the faulty behaviour :(

Comment: As your answer was the most elaborated one, you receive the reputation.

Comment: Sorry I only had partial details to go on, I couldn't see your control hierarchy or your data-binding logic. Did you get it working?

Comment: Yes, i posted one line which had to be exchanged as an update into the question.

Comment: @James That looks like it will work with DataGrid but DataGridView has not been added to UIAVerify definition. If someone could point that out, then that link to the code will no doubt work.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks fine though this *could* be a focus issue.

Even though you are getting a reference to these automation element objects you should set focus on them (using the aptly named [SetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.setfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method) before using them.

Try:

```
var desktop = AutomationElement.RootElement;

desktop.SetFocus();

// Find AutomationElement for the App's window
var bw = desktop.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, (int)processID));
```

and if that does not work try explicitly focusing on the dataGrid prior to calling "FindAll" on it i.e.

```
datagrid.SetFocus()
```

Comment: When trying to SetFocus on desktop, I receive an InvalidOperationException - focussing the desktop is apparently not possible.

Comment: Focussing the DataGridView didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Why does the DataGridView return 0 rows?

The DataGridViewRows have a ControlType of ControlType.Custom. So I modified the line

```
// Find all rows from the DataGridView
var loginLines = datagrid.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.DataItem));
```

To

```
var loginLines = datagrid.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Custom));
```

That gets you all the rows within the DataGridView. But your code has that within the loop.

What pattern is supported by DataGridView (not DataGrid)?

LegacyIAccessiblePattern. Try this-

```
 LegacyIAccessiblePattern legacyPattern = null;

       try
       {
           legacyPattern = datagrid.GetCurrentPattern(LegacyIAccessiblePattern.Pattern) as LegacyIAccessiblePattern;
       }
       catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
       {
           // It passes!
       }
```

As I commented on @James answer, there is no support for UIA for DataGridView (again, not DataGrid).

If you search in google with terms: "UI Automation DataGridView" the [first result](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/25d6b3a6-1533-4fae-85a7-6cc553c8c9a7/datagridview-extended-to-implement-ui-automation?forum=windowsaccessibilityandautomation) has an incomplete answer. Mike replies with what provider class (Obviously one that extends DataGridView)to create within the source, unfortunately I have no clue as to how to make UIA load that class a provider. If anyone can shed some clues, Phil and I will be extremely pleased!

**EDIT**

Your DataGridView should implement the interfaces in that link above. Once you do that the ControlType of Row will be ControlType.DataItem instead of ControlType.Custom. You can then use it how you'd use a DataGrid.

**EDIT**

This is what I ended up doing -

Creating a Custom DataGridView like below. Your datagridview could subclass this too. That will make it support ValuePattern and SelectionItemPattern.

```
public class CommonDataGridView : System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView,
    IRawElementProviderFragmentRoot,
    IGridProvider,
    ISelectionProvider
{.. }
```

The complete code can be found @ [this msdn link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/25d6b3a6-1533-4fae-85a7-6cc553c8c9a7/datagridview-extended-to-implement-ui-automation?forum=windowsaccessibilityandautomation).

Once I did that, I played a bit with visualUIVerify source. Here is how I can access the gridview's cell and change the value. Also, make note of the commented code. I didn't need that. It allows you to iterate through rows and cells.

```
private void _automationElementTree_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //selected currentTestTypeRootNode has been changed so notify change to AutomationTests Control
        AutomationElementTreeNode selectedNode = _automationElementTree.SelectedNode;
        AutomationElement selectedElement = null;

        if (selectedNode != null)
        {
            selectedElement = selectedNode.AutomationElement;

            if (selectedElement.Current.ClassName.Equals("AutomatedDataGrid.CommonDataGridViewCell"))
            {
                if(selectedElement.Current.Name.Equals("Tej")) //Current Value
                {

                    var valuePattern = selectedElement.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;

                    valuePattern.SetValue("Jet");
                }



                //Useful ways to get patterns and values

                //System.Windows.Automation.SelectionItemPattern pattern = selectedElement.GetCurrentPattern(System.Windows.Automation.SelectionItemPattern.Pattern) as System.Windows.Automation.SelectionItemPattern;


                //var row = pattern.Current.SelectionContainer.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "AutomatedDataGrid.CommonDataGridViewRow", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase));

                //var cells = row.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "AutomatedDataGrid.CommonDataGridViewCell", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase));
                //foreach (AutomationElement cell in cells)
                //{
                //    Console.WriteLine("**** Printing Cell Value **** " + cell.Current.Name);

                //    if(cell.Current.Name.Equals("Tej")) //current name
                //    {

                //        var valuePattern = cell.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;

                //        valuePattern.SetValue("Suraj");
                //    }
                //}

                //Select Row
                //pattern.Select();

                //Get All Rows
                //var arrayOfRows = pattern.Current.SelectionContainer.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "AutomatedDataGrid.CommonDataGridViewRow", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase));


                //get cells
                //foreach (AutomationElement row in arrayOfRows)
                //{
                //   var cell = row.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "AutomatedDataGrid.CommonDataGridViewCell", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase));


                //    var gridItemPattern = cell.GetCurrentPattern(GridItemPattern.Pattern) as GridItemPattern;

                //    // Row number.
                //    Console.WriteLine("**** Printing Row Number **** " + gridItemPattern.Current.Row);

                //    //Cell Automation ID
                //    Console.WriteLine("**** Printing Cell AutomationID **** " + cell.Current.AutomationId);

                //    //Cell Class Name
                //    Console.WriteLine("**** Printing Cell ClassName **** " + cell.Current.ClassName);

                //    //Cell Name
                //    Console.WriteLine("**** Printing Cell AutomationID **** " + cell.Current.Name);                        
                //}

            }
        }

        _automationTests.SelectedElement = selectedElement;
        _automationElementPropertyGrid.AutomationElement = selectedElement;
    }
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Is there an alternative for LegacyIAccessiblePattern working with .net framework 4.0?

Comment: Yep, convert it into a recognizable pattern like the SelectionItemPattern in my latest edit above.

Answer (score 1):

I run into this problem too, after researching, i figured out that you can only access data grid view with `LegacyIAccessible`. However, .NET does not support this. So, here are the steps:

1. there are 2 versions of UIA: managed version and unmanaged version (native code). In some cases, the unmanaged version can do what the managed version can't.

=> as said here, using `tblimp.exe` (go along with Windows SDK) to generate a COM wrapper around the unmanaged UIA API, so we can call from C#.
I have done it [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/rrhon6abl29nu9i/interop.UIAutomationCore.dll)

2. we can use this to access DataGridView now but with very limited data, you can use `Inspect.exe` to see.

The code is:

```
using InteropUIA = interop.UIAutomationCore;

if (senderElement.Current.ControlType.Equals(ControlType.Custom))
{
    var automation = new InteropUIA.CUIAutomation();
    var element = automation.GetFocusedElement();
    var pattern = (InteropUIA.IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern)element.GetCurrentPattern(10018);
    Logger.Info(string.Format("{0}: {1} - Selected", pattern.CurrentName, pattern.CurrentValue));
}
```